Why is exit status of grep not working in this script?
Here is the script:
echo a | grep b
if [ $? ]; then
    echo b
fi

I expect it not to print anything.

[ with exactly one argument before ] tests if the argument is a non-empty string. In your case what $? expands to is a non-empty string and the test succeeds.
[ "$?" -eq 0 ] would check if $? is numerically equal to 0. I guess this is closer to what you want to do.
Note [ is not syntax, it is a command. In general the whole thing between if and then is a snippet of shell code whose final exit status matters for if. In case of if [ "$?" -eq 0 ]; then the relevant exit status comes from [. This exit status trivially depends on the exit status of the previous command (stored in $?); why not to use the previous command directly then? You can (and should) do if echo a | grep b; then instead of playing with $?. Testing the value of $? when you can directly rely on the exit status is bad practice.
Fixed:
if echo a | grep b; then
    echo b
fi


I have seen the use of $? in if statements quite frequently. Is this something from Bourne shell that does not work in bash? Find that quite strange. I tried to save it in another variable and use that in the if statement which works!

@sureshvv You can use $? inside if. Here the problem was you implemented a test (your [ command) that does not test what you wanted.

See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15471264/how-to-check-if-is-not-equal-to-zero-in-unix-shell-scripting All very similar code

@sureshvv What is your point?

That [ ] is not overwriting the $? in those examples

@sureshvv I still don't know what you mean. Your [ $? ] made no sense. [ "$?" -eq 0 ] makes some sense, still it's better to use the last command directly between if and then, without [, as shown in my answer. What exactly is the problem now? and how is the linked SO question related to this problem?

I assumed [ $? ] to mean the same as [ $? -eq 0]. That was my error. Thanks for clearing it up.
